# How can I remove the last character in a String that has another regex computation in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove the following character from a String: <,>,t,d,/ and also to remove the last character after the first removal. And I want to do this on a single statement.

Regex for removing <,>,t,d,/:

```
 String codCIM =  element.toString().replaceAll("[<>,t,d,//]", ""); -WORKS FINE
```

Regex for removing <,>,t,d,/ AND the last character:

```
String codCIM =  element.toString().replaceAll("[<>,t,d,//].$", ""); -DONT WORK
```

Ex: `"dtt>W43451005/dttt>"` should be `W4345100`.
But I can only achieve: `W43451005`

Comment: So `ttt>123ddd>456>>>` should become `12456`? Or is there only ever one continuous center string that is kept?

Comment: Note that `[<>,t,d,//]` is identical to `[<>,td/]`, I think you mean `[<>td/]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use this regex: `[<>td/]|.(?=[<>td/]*$)`

[regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/dM4h9H/2)

---

- `[<>td/]` matches the target characters;
- `.(?=[<>td/]*$)` matches the character before *the ending target character sequence*, which is basically the last character after removing all target characters;

Answer (score 1):

First, the expected output shows that a sequence consisting of `d, t, <, >, /` should be removed, and *then* the character *before* this match *at the end of the string* has to be removed.

This can be achieved with the following regexp:

```java
System.out.println("dtt>W43451005/dttt>".replaceAll("([<>td/]|.[<>td/]*$)", ""));
```

Output

```
W4345100
```